# magic header not detected File was processed with these loaders: * ./node_modules/wasm-loader/index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webassembly

I have issue using webassembly wasm file in React with Typescript.

I have install `react-app-rewired` and `wasm-loader` and my config-overrides.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  const wasmExtensionRegExp = /\.wasm$/;

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.wasm');

  config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
    (rule.oneOf || []).forEach(oneOf => {
      if (oneOf.loader && oneOf.loader.indexOf('file-loader') >= 0) {
        // make file-loader ignore WASM files
        oneOf.exclude.push(wasmExtensionRegExp);
      }
    });
  });

  // add a dedicated loader for WASM
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: wasmExtensionRegExp,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    use: [{ loader: require.resolve('wasm-loader'), options: {} }]
  });

  return config;
};
```

in package json I change to use `"start": "react-app-rewired start",`
but still have the same error.
How can solve this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"magic header not detected" indicates that your `.wasm` file is not really a `.wasm` file. Can you verify that it is a valid file using [`wasm-objdump`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/)?